Whats with the change in voice name en-US-Wavenet-F?
Sometime past April it seems that the voice names were changed...I'm not sure why. I have attached an example of a comparison. The new voices are of poor quality than the previous ones.
Examples (https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1B6paiY-St6LgpPkOjTgdsRmlyXdHotDP?usp=drive_link)
has anyone had the same issue?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
